# Accordion styled list to toggle correctly

Tags: jquery, css, accordion

I have this accordion which is working almost correctly, if you click each item individually it does what it's supposed to do. If you click other items when one item is active however is when the bugs start to appear as I'm not sure how to proceed with toggling the states for the siblings, they do slide up correctly, but i would also like them to change back to it's original color, the .fa icon to it's original state and the border bottom to re-appear. I have an example in Codepen:

https://codepen.io/SergiOca/pen/dWexdW

```
 <body>

<div class="accordion-wrap">
              <div class="accordion-item">
                <p class="accordion-header"> Bordado <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> </p>
              </div>
              <div class="accordion-text">
                <p> Básica y de fantasía con apliques, metálicos, flocado, purpurina, lentejuelas, bolas, brillantes… alta frecuencia, sublimación, tránsfer, láser, hueco grabado, serigrafía digital, vinilo textil. </p>
              </div>
           </div>


           <div class="accordion-wrap">
              <div class="accordion-item">
                <p class="accordion-header"> Bordado <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> </p>
              </div>
              <div class="accordion-text">
                <p> Básica y de fantasía con apliques, metálicos, flocado, purpurina, lentejuelas, bolas, brillantes… alta frecuencia, sublimación, tránsfer, láser, hueco grabado, serigrafía digital, vinilo textil. </p>
              </div>
           </div>


            <div class="accordion-wrap">
              <div class="accordion-item">
                <p class="accordion-header"> Bordado <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> </p>
              </div>
              <div class="accordion-text">
                <p> Básica y de fantasía con apliques, metálicos, flocado, purpurina, lentejuelas, bolas, brillantes… alta frecuencia, sublimación, tránsfer, láser, hueco grabado, serigrafía digital, vinilo textil. </p>
              </div>
           </div>


</body>



body{
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 5%;
}

.accordion-item{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddba4d;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.accordion-wrap{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddba4d;
}

.accordion-header{
  transition: ease-in-out 100ms;
}

.accordion-text{
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddba4d;
  display: none;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
 }

 .fa{
    transition: ease-in-out 300ms;
 }

 .rotate-fa{
    transform: rotate(180deg);
 }


 .accordion-header .fa{
    float: right;
    line-height: 35px;
 }

 .accordion-gold{
    color: #ddba4d;
 }

 .accordion-no-bar{
    border-bottom: 0;
 }


    $(".accordion-wrap").on("click", function(){   
      $(this).children().eq(1).slideToggle(300);  
      $(this).find(".accordion-header").toggleClass("accordion-gold");
      $(this).find(".fa").toggleClass("rotate-fa");

      $(".accordion-wrap .accordion-text").not($(this).children().eq(1)).slideUp(300); 
  });
```

Comment: you missed the html code inside the example

Comment: Sorry, it's back again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the codepen that you created in the first place, I've added a method that removed every other `accordion-gold`- classes.

So i added a line of javascript-code to your existing code:

```
$(this).siblings().find(".accordion-header").removeClass("accordion-gold");
```

And if you apply this to your code it should look something like this:

```
/* acordion */
$(".accordion-wrap").on("click", function(){   
    $(this).children().eq(1).slideToggle(300);  
    $(this).children().eq(0).toggleClass("accordion-no-bar");
    $(this).siblings().find(".accordion-header").removeClass("accordion-gold");
    $(this).find(".accordion-header").toggleClass("accordion-gold");
    $(this).find(".fa").toggleClass("rotate-fa");

    $(".accordion-wrap .accordion-text").not($(this).children().eq(1)).slideUp(300);
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That works great, also adding " $(this).siblings().find(".accordion-header i").removeClass("rotate-fa");" now achieves everything I wanted. Thank you.

Comment: @Sergi this answer doesn't solve your problem of no bar. Check again

Comment: Sorry I solved the no bar problem myself and edited the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also.

```js
/* acordion */
$(".accordion-wrap").on("click", function() {
  $(this).children().eq(1).slideToggle(300);
  $(this).children().eq(0).toggleClass("accordion-no-bar");
  $(this).find(".accordion-header").toggleClass("accordion-gold");
  $(this).find(".fa").toggleClass("rotate-fa");
  $(".accordion-wrap .accordion-text").not($(this).children().eq(1)).slideUp(300);
  $(".accordion-wrap .accordion-item").not($(this).children().eq(0)).removeClass("accordion-no-bar");
  $(this).siblings().find(".accordion-header").removeClass("accordion-gold");
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 5%;
}

.accordion-item {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddba4d;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.accordion-header {
  transition: ease-in-out 100ms;
}

.accordion-text {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddba4d;
  display: none;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.fa {
  transition: ease-in-out 300ms;
}

.rotate-fa {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.accordion-header .fa {
  float: right;
  line-height: 35px;
}

.accordion-gold {
  color: #ddba4d;
}

.accordion-no-bar {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="accordion-wrap">
    <div class="accordion-item">
      <p class="accordion-header"> Bordado <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> </p>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-text">
      <p> Básica y de fantasía con apliques, metálicos, flocado, purpurina, lentejuelas, bolas, brillantes… alta frecuencia, sublimación, tránsfer, láser, hueco grabado, serigrafía digital, vinilo textil. </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-wrap">
    <div class="accordion-item">
      <p class="accordion-header"> Bordado <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> </p>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-text">
      <p> Básica y de fantasía con apliques, metálicos, flocado, purpurina, lentejuelas, bolas, brillantes… alta frecuencia, sublimación, tránsfer, láser, hueco grabado, serigrafía digital, vinilo textil. </p>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="accordion-wrap">
    <div class="accordion-item">
      <p class="accordion-header"> Bordado <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> </p>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-text">
      <p> Básica y de fantasía con apliques, metálicos, flocado, purpurina, lentejuelas, bolas, brillantes… alta frecuencia, sublimación, tránsfer, láser, hueco grabado, serigrafía digital, vinilo textil. </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```